# How to declare a blob in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to do some tests to my database (like turning off the machine while it's still writing something).
To do this, I'm planning to insert a movie file into the database with 700mb, so that I can have time to insert it and turn it off (instead of being something done instantaneously).

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and the closest I can find in the data types is Binary(50). Is this enough for what I want?

I want to know which data type must the column that will store this large file be.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`Binary(50)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) will hold 50 bytes - this is not going to be enough to hold 700mb.

From MSDN:

> binary [ ( n ) ]
>
> Fixed-length binary data with a length of n bytes, where n is a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is n bytes.

You should use `VARBINARY(MAX)`:

> Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

You could also use [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), though it is deprecated.