# How can I store long text data in embedded SQL Server CE database of C# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am working on a C# application. I use an embedded SQL Server CE database.

I want to store long text data in that database, but there is limit of 4000 char on the `nvarchar` datatype in the SQL Server CE database (`.sdf`).

Is there any solution for it? How can I store long text data in embedded C# application?
or should i go for any other embedded database?

Comment: All databases supports `blob` (binary array). If you don't mind to have to convert string<->bytes, then [use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240858/how-to-declare-a-blob-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ntext` data type in the SQL Server CE database.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx) contains more information:

> *ntext:* Variable-length Unicode data with a maximum length of
>   (2^30–2)/2 (536,870,911) characters. Storage size, in bytes, is two
>   times the number of characters entered.