# How to add text file for each new user created in database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015, authentication, text-files

I have a program which enables me to create a new user. To add a new user the program asks for a username and a password. Picture below.

[image: Create New User]

When the user types a username and a password, then clicks save, the username and the password is saved into a table which I have created through Visual Studio 2015, in a database which has also been created through this IDE.

I need, upon creation of a new user, for the program to create a new text file *for that particular new user*. Then when a user logs in using this window,

[image: Login Window]

their own text file which was created should appear in a text box which they can add things to. Every time they log in, they view *their own text file.* This takes place in this window

[image: Accounts Window]

The save button, saves any edits to the text file in question, and the load button should load the text file. Ideally, I would like to remove the load button and have the content of the text file shown straight into the text box.

I have tried to work around this by breaking it down to pieces. I know a .txt needs to be created upon saving a new user, but I don't know where to go from there. I'm hoping for a solution that will enable the program to work on any machine.

I have looked up on the internet about database user files, creating a new user with files etc and the only thing I found was a question on here and it turns out that a database isn't a good solution to store text files. I have checked MSDN, YouTube, on YouTube I found how to upload an image to a user in a database, but not a text file.

Can anybody help me on this? It doesn't have to be code in particular just the steps in general then I can gladly look things up.

Comment: Databases don't tend to store files at all.... but how much data are we talking about here?  How big are the files?

Comment: It will be literally lines of text. They will be small files, literally KB. Users won't be many either. Ideally I'd be able to support about 15 users maximum.

Comment: A database can handle that just fine.

Comment: I thought about adding new text files as resources from within the project but then I wasn't sure how to marry a particular text file to a user. Generally I can't seem to get the mindset of this kind of setup. This is probably why I can't get info from the net. I'm probably not wording things probably in my searches.

Comment: I see you WHAT you want to do, but are you sure that's HOW you want to do it? As others have pointed out, you could save data to the text file. You could also save a text file to the DB. But why not saving the text that the user enters directly into the DB?

Comment: OK so my approach should be on how to create a new user and store a text file for that user in the database? Is this accurate?

Comment: I'm new to databases I'm just going on simple thoughts, I'm not sure what the best approach is. I don't have an opinion on this kind of thing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated the type of sql databasse, I assume it for sql-server.

For small files you can use binary or varbinary as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240903/7564182).

For really bigger files as your requirement here the [documentation on BLOBs in SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server)

Comment: OK. I'll have a look and get back.

Comment: I've found this which looks good.  http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/05/How-to-Store-and-Retrieve-File-in-SQL-Server-using-CSharp.html?m=1#InsertAsBinary I can't seem to find how to "tie" this new text file to a particular user so that when the user logs in their own text file loads. I'll look into that and get back.